# How to register a queue and it's exclusive consumer/listener dynamically for RabbitMQ and Spring?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have the following problem to be solved:
I am trying to implement a simple delayed retry mechanism using RabbitMQ messaging. I am having an infrastructure which provides me the delay in delivering the message. I can have any number of interested participants who would like to leverage this delayed retry mechanism at the runtime.

The participants want to provide me with only 2 details and the message:
 1. The queue name where they want the message to be delivered after a delay of say T seconds.
 2. The consumer of the queue( say a Consumer of the message.)

I have tried to do the following:

```
private void startSeparateListener(final Object messageConsumer, 
                                   final Queue queue) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer 
                    = myCustomeSimpleMessageListenerFactory.create();
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setRabbitAdmin(rabbitAdmin);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setQueues(queue);
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(messageConsumer));
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.start();

    }
```

Please note, that the queue has been created and registered already with rabbitadmin and the object consumer has a method named handleMessage to listen to the queue.

Is this the right way to register a queue dynamically with the message consumer for the queue at the runtime?

Notes:
Spring already provides a bean of type SimpleMessageListenerContainer but would using the bean to add queues and consumer dynamically would cause the issue of the unintended consumer of say Q1 being called as part of receiver of another queue say Q2 whose content type might be the same of the Q1?

I tried searching a lot about it but couldn't get hold of any concrete explanation. Apologies beforehand if it is a repeat question and for any naivety.

Answer (score 0):

I can't compile your question somehow, but what I can tell that there is already Dealyed Exchange solution in the RabbitMQ and Sring AMQP [supports](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#delayed-message-exchange) it well.

I would suggest to stay away from dynamically added `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`: it's not so simply as it seems. There is an option like `addQueueNames()`:

```
/**
 * Add queue(s) to this container's list of queues. The existing consumers
 * will be cancelled after they have processed any pre-fetched messages and
 * new consumers will be created. The queue must exist to avoid problems when
 * restarting the consumers.
 * @param queueName The queue to add.
 */
@Override
public void addQueueNames(String... queueName) {
```

So, you may consider not add new containers but add new queues to the existing one. Downstream routing by the `amqp_consumerQueue` may help to distinguish messages from different queues.

Comment: Dear @artem-bilan, Thank you for the response. My apologies is I couldn't put the question well. I am aware of the delayed exchange plugin, however I have created my own delaying infrastructure using Exchanges and Queues with x-message-ttl and x-deadletter-exchange defined appropriately. This entire infra sends all the messages into a sink exchange. I wanted to create a queue, bind it to the exchange and register a consumer for the queue as well, all in the runtime. Hence my question of creating a new SimpleMessageListenerContainer and using it. I hope I could explain it better.